# Kendo 3 Tier Cascading DropDownList

Tags: kendo-ui, cascadingdropdown, kendo-combobox

Im trying to do a simple cascading dropdownist but for some reason the 3 drop down list isnt cascading correctly. Is cascading the engineType from the previous dropdownlist nut not taking into count the make.

for example select make->Audi, then EngineType->Deisel. the 3 dropdownlist should show 'A4'. but it shows all Deisel engines.

any help would be great on this.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  var makes = $("#makes").kendoDropDownList({
        autoBind: true,
        optionLabel: "Select",
        dataTextField: "make",
        dataValueField: "make",
        dataSource: [
            { make: "Audi"},
            { make: "BMW" },
            { make: "Saab"}
        ]
  }).data("kendoDropDownList");

  var engineType = $("#engineTypes").kendoDropDownList({
        autoBind: false,
        cascadeFrom: "makes",
        optionLabel: "Select",
        dataTextField: "engineType",
        dataValueField: "engineType",
        dataSource: [
            { make: "Audi", engineType: "Deisel"},
            { make: "Audi", engineType: "Petrol"},
            { make: "BMW", engineType: "Deisel"},
            { make: "Saab", engineType: "Deisel"}
        ]
  }).data("kendoDropDownList");

  var models = $("#models").kendoDropDownList({
        autoBind: false,
        cascadeFrom: "engineTypes",
        optionLabel: "Select",
        dataTextField: "chose",
        dataValueField: "chose",
        dataSource: [
          { make: "Audi", engineType: "Deisel", chose: "A4"},
            { make: "Audi", engineType: "Petrol", chose: "A5"},
            { make: "BMW", engineType: "Deisel", chose: "3 Series"},
            { make: "Saab", engineType: "Deisel", chose: "900"}
        ]
  }).data("kendoDropDownList");

});
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused because the second dropdownlist (engine types) contains duplicate values. You need to give each item some unique value. Something like this:

```
 var engineType = $("#engineTypes").kendoDropDownList({
        autoBind: false,
        cascadeFrom: "makes",
        optionLabel: "Select",
        dataTextField: "engineType",
        dataValueField: "value",
        dataSource: [
          { make: "Audi", engineType: "Deisel", value: 1 },
          { make: "Audi", engineType: "Petrol", value: 2 },
          { make: "BMW", engineType: "Deisel", value: 3 },
          { make: "Saab", engineType: "Deisel", value: 4}
        ]
  }).data("kendoDropDownList");

  var models = $("#models").kendoDropDownList({
        autoBind: false,
        cascadeFrom: "engineTypes",
        optionLabel: "Select",
        dataTextField: "chose",
        dataValueField: "chose",
        dataSource: [
          { make: "Audi", value: 1, chose: "A4"},
          { make: "Audi", value: 2, chose: "A5"},
          { make: "BMW", value: 3, chose: "3 Series"},
          { make: "Saab", value: 4, chose: "900"}
        ]
  }).data("kendoDropDownList");
```

Here is a live demo: http://jsbin.com/izahAWi/1/edit

Comment: thanks your a lifesaver. been driving me mad. I used the data above as an example, i actually have a mySQL table which has a matrix of cars which i want to make the cascading dropdowns from. would this be possible from one json datasource which has fields make, engine, model, variant. would love your help on this. to summarise i would want 4 cascading dropdownlst make, engine, model, variant from one datasource matrix. Sample data - [link](http://projects.quayhosting.co.uk/hyperchips/data/sample.php)